# using aref inside a dotimes loop in CL?

Tags: arrays, loops, lisp, common-lisp

I have an array with dimensions '(3 3 2) as follows with name test-array:

```
#3A(((0 0) (0 0.1) (0 0.3)) 
    ((1 0) (1 0.1) (1 0.3))
    ((2 0) (2 0.1) (2 0.3)))
```

Note that the most inner lists inside the array (rank 2) are point coordinates, So in general the array would be

```
#3A(((x0 y0) (x0 y1) (x0 y2)) 
    ((x1 y0) (x1 y1) (x1 y2))
    ((x2 y0) (x2 y1) (x2 y2)))
```

Now I want to use the elements inside this array to make a new array.

On every row (array-rank: 0) of this array, I want to subtract the second xy coordinates from the first and the third xy coordinates from the second. So basically the result that I am looking for in parametric form is:

```
#3A(((x0-x0 y1-y0) (x0-x0 y2-y1)) 
    ((x1-x1 y1-y0) (x1-x1 y2-y1))
    ((x2-x2 y1-y0) (x2-x2 y2-y1))
```

Is there any simple direct function or operation which does this by only manipulating the initial array?

Since I don't know any direct operation for this, I thought of just making a list out of the initial array to be the `:initial-contents` of the new array. So the initial aim in this approach would be to get the initial-contents list which is:

```
   (((x0-x0 y1-y0) (x0-x0 y2-y1)) 
    ((x1-x1 y1-y0) (x1-x1 y2-y1))
    ((x2-x2 y1-y0) (x2-x2 y2-y1))
```

To do this I thought of a code which uses `dotimes` twice (number of outer loops would be the number of rows and number of inner loops would be the number of columns so to say):

```
(let ((result-1))
  (dotimes (n (array-dimension test-array 0) result-1)
    (setq result-1
      (append result-1
              (let ((result-2))
                (dotimes (m (1- (array-dimension test-array 1)) result-2)
                  (setq result-2
                    (append result-2 
                            (list (- (aref test-array n (1+ m) 0)
                                     (aref test-array n m 0))
                                  (- (aref test-array n (1+ m) 1)
                                     (aref test-array n m 1)))))))))))
```

But there is one problem with this which is also the title of the question. Apparently this "parametric" way (using n & m) of giving inputs for `aref` is not appreciated by CL: `(aref test-array n m 0)`

Why is there such a problem? Can you think of any other way to use aref inside the loops or maybe make the :initial-contents list with another approach?

Note that this is a relatively simple form of my actual question because the actual initial array that I have has dimensions of (21 16 2) and all the x y coordinates are different from each other.

Answers would be really appreciated...

Comment: It would be appreciated by CL if you used `1+` (which is a function name) instead of `+1` (which is another way of writing `1`).

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Yes, Just noticed and changed it. It was a typing error!

Comment: This change invalidates the "main question in your question", so you might want to edit it accordingly. I've tried to answer the rest of the question nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noticed in a comment, the function returning its argument
incremented by 1 is `1+`, not `+1` (which is not a function name but a
constant `1`).

I see no need to construct `:initial-contents` here, as it does not
make things easier than constructing the target array and filling it
in a loop as a separate step. That's how I would do it:

```
(defparameter *test-array*
  #3A(((0 0) (0 0.1) (0 0.3)) 
      ((1 0) (1 0.1) (1 0.3))
      ((2 0) (2 0.1) (2 0.3))))

(destructuring-bind (rows cols axes) (array-dimensions *test-array*)
  (let ((result (make-array
                 (list rows (1- cols) axes)
                 :element-type (array-element-type *test-array*))))
    (dotimes (row rows result)
      (dotimes (col (1- cols))
        (dotimes (axis axes)
          (setf (aref result row col axis)
                (- (aref *test-array* row (1+ col) axis)
                   (aref *test-array* row col axis))))))))
```

I decided to make this example as simple as possible. Alternative
solutions are possible, e.g. making use of a vector displaced to the
array (that's how you work with pieces of multidimensional arrays
using sequence functions).  I would prefer the simple approach for
*this* task if not for more complicated cases.